# How to prevent access to direct directory URL but allow directory contents in IIS6?

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-6, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an image hosting site set up in IIS, for example the products folder would be `www.foobar.com/products/`. Is this any way to prevent public access to this link, but allow public access to links such as `www.foobar.com/products/some_product.jpg`?

For some reason this folder doesn't return a 403 error, but the rest of the folders do. I don't see any differences in security settings under folder properties.

Comment: You mixed a few tags that cannot be related to each other (IIS 6 isn't available on Windows Server 2008 R2), so I wonder what exactly is the environment you are using. If you happen to use IIS 7 and above, FRT can print out the actual activities behind any HTTP request https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis if you set HTTP status to `200-999`. That can answer what is the reason that "this folder doesn't return a 403 error".

Comment: According to your description, you want to prevent customers from accessing `www.foobar.com/products/`, but allow direct access to `www.foobar.com/products/some_product.jpg`, right? Did you enable default document?